# Wikipedia style tooltip with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What library is used for Wikipedia's tooltip when you hover over a reference link (`[1]`)?

Or maybe there's a library that mimics that functionality (allowing you to insert a lot of different HTML elements and such).

The desired library needs to be able to work with jQuery/jqUI (so it can't be prototype based and such) or it could just work on its own.

Comment: FYI, I believe you can still use jQuery even with Prototype. Just use `jQuery.noConflict();` or define another variable which you set to `$` between Prototype & jQuery (that should work, logically, but I've never tried it).

Comment: On a side note, I would just write my own - it is easy enough to do and you would learn a lot more from that than using a plugin. I only tend to use 3rd party plugins if I am in a hurry to get a complex job done.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, yup. That's exactly my reasoning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small amount of googling, you could have found many articles and source codes:

1. http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/
2. Wikipedia tool-tip jQuery: http://finndorby.com/?p=184